# Formatting Spaces, punctuation marks in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Provide an alphabetical list of students in area code 203. List student name in the format , . ( Example, LOCKE, J. ) followed by the phone number.

this is my SQL script

```
SELECT
CONCAT(UPPER(LAST_NAME) , UPPER(SUBSTR(FIRST_NAME, 1, 1))) AS "Student Name", PHONE
FROM
STUDENT s 
WHERE 
PHONE LIKE '203%'
ORDER BY 
LAST_NAME
```

The information I pulled from SQL is correct, I just need to fix the formatting to LASTNAME(space) FIRST INITIAL followed by period.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I am still very new to SQL and programming.

I am using Oracle SQL

Comment: you can concat a bunch of strings by using `||`. For example `LAST_NAME || ' ' || FIRST_NAME || '.'`

Comment: SELECT
UPPER(LAST_NAME) ||' '|| UPPER(SUBSTR(FIRST_NAME, 1, 1))||'.' AS "Student Name", PHONE 
FROM
STUDENT s 
WHERE 
PHONE LIKE '203%'
ORDER BY 
LAST_NAME  It works perfectly. Thank you so much.